# sass script variables in a @each directive

Tags: sass

I have this snippet of code in my scss file:

```sass
$ttk-bg-green: #99FF00;
$ttk-bg-orange: #FFBE00;
$ttk-bg-purple: #CD66FF;
$ttk-bg-blue: #55BBFF;

$ttk-icon-green: #80D500;
$ttk-icon-orange: #FFAF37;
$ttk-icon-purple: #CD66FF;
$ttk-icon-blue: #62C0FF;
```

```sass
$color-types: "bg" "icon";
$color-styles: "green" "orange" "purple" "blue";
@each $color-type in $color-types {
  @each $color-style in $color-styles {
    .ttk-#{$color-type}-#{$color-style} { color: $ttk-#{$color-type}-#{$color-style}; }
  }
}
```

it's supposed to generate something along the lines of:
.ttk-bg-green: #99FF00;

The compass compiler fails to compile the code, saying $ttk variable does not exist.
it just fails to recognize it as a whole variable.
ideas? solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass @each variable interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970413/sass-each-variable-interpolation)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Didn't find an answer to my needs.