# Generate different variables in SASS using @each (precompile)

Tags: sass, each

How to generate different variables use `@each`, precompile and not to generate html classes, just generate scss variables:

_pattern_factory.scss:

```
$patt:(a , b, c, d, e);
@each $style in $patt {
  $pattern_#{$style}: url('../img/#{$style}.png');
}
```

`@import` to main_variables.scss.

And than generate:

```
$pattern_a: url('../img/pattern-a.png');
$pattern_b: url('../img/pattern-b.png');
$pattern_c: url('../img/pattern-c.png');
$pattern_d: url('../img/pattern-d.png');
$pattern_e: url('../img/pattern-e.png');
```

(inside main_variables.scss)

Or we must write manually...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass @each variable interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970413/sass-each-variable-interpolation)