# Can SCSS output less CSS Code?

Tags: css, while-loop, sass, compass-sass

I am wondering if there's a way to output lesser lines of CSS using SCSS.

```
@each $cover in cover-cat, cover-dog, cover-bird {
    .#{$cover} {
        @include bg-no-repeat-center('backgrounds/' + $cover + '.png');
        @include screen-size-absolute;
        @if $cover == cover-cat {
        z-index: 10;
    } @else if $cover == cover-dog {
        z-index: 20;
    } @else {
        z-index: 15;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
  }
}
```

and that output to this:

```
    .cover-cat {
background: url("../images/backgrounds/cover-cat.png") center center no-repeat;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.cover-bird {
background: url("../images/backgrounds/cover-bird.png") center center no-repeat;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.cover-dog {
background: url("../images/backgrounds/cover-dog.png") center center no-repeat;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Is there a way to make it look like this instead:

```
.cover-dog {
background: url("../images/backgrounds/cover-dog.png") center center no-repeat;
z-index: 20;
}

.cover-cat {
background: url("../images/backgrounds/cover-cat.png") center center no-repeat;
z-index: 10;
}

.cover-bird {
background: url("../images/backgrounds/cover-bird.png") center center no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
z-index: 15;
}

.cover-dog,
.cover-cat,
.cover-bird {
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

...thought it would be less lines of codes. :) I'm a newbie in scss. Hope someone can help or enlighten me! Thanks!

Comment: Typically, SCSS doesn't output less code. Instead it helps you build modular, reusable pieces of CSS that can be included in other files so that you can have the least amount of CSS for each page possible.

The old way, you would end up having very large global CSS files that contain irrelevant styles. This way, you can have a unique CSS file for the page view and one for the truly global elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass @each variable interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970413/sass-each-variable-interpolation)

Comment: Thank you Harvey! I was thinking maybe I was just missing some SCSS feature that can handle it :)