# Sass variable prefix

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible to create something like this with SASS?

```
$prefix: *

*-var1: 150px
*-var2: 150px
*-var3: 350px
```

This could be very useful for organising a stylesheet

Comment: did you try it, you could always use an array $prefix('150', etc)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970413/sass-each-variable-interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sass 3.3 there are a couple of new features that will likely solve your need for doing this, and greatly help with organizing stylesheets

You now have maps, which allow you to essentially create objects containing variables.

You can do the following:

```
$colors: (
  header: #b06,
  text: #334,
  footer: #666777,
)

.header {
  background-color: map-get($colors, header)
}
```

As well as the new ability to prefix css selectors like so:

```
// Sass:
.button {
  &-primary { background: orange; }
  &-secondary { background: blue; }
}

// Output:
.button-primary { background: orange; }
.button-secondary { background: blue; }
```

Further reading: http://thesassway.com/news/sass-3-3-released

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely...

SASS:

```
$variableName: "myStyle";

#{$variableName}_r1{ border: 1px solid red; }
```

Produces CSS:

```
myStyle_r1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The key is the interpolation - #{$variableName} - which basically dumps the variableName out as it was written...

Comment: It looks like he want to define variables depending on another variable, not properties.